# Using logical operators instead of control flow?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, if-statement, logical-operators

I will keep this short.
I was reviewing code for Hex Filter (To filter out non-character ASCII values)

code:

```
HEX_FILTER = ''.join([(len(repr(chr(i))) == 3) and chr(i) or '.' for i in range(256)])
```

Output:

```
................................ !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[.]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~..................................¡¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª«¬.®¯°±²³´µ¶·¸¹º»¼½¾¿ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõö÷øùúûüýþÿ
```

I was confused on what's going on, so I wrote my approach to get above output. My code is as follows:

```
HEX_FILTER = ''.join(['.' if (len(repr(chr(i))) != 3) else chr(i) for i in range(256)])
```

The idea is `repr` of non-alphabet will be more than 3. If it's not 3 use '.' else use the character.

I cannot wrap my mind around on as to, How `len(repr(chr(i))) == 3) and chr(i) or '.'` equates to `'.' if (len(repr(chr(i))) != 3) else chr(i)`

Comment: One easy-ish way to see if there is a difference is to write a script to loop thru all the T/F values for the 3 pieces of the 2 code versions and print out a truth table for each. There's only 2^3 = 8 combinations. But maybe you already know there isn't a difference, since that is your question...

Comment: Yes, I know both codes yield the same result. I was a little surprised to notice `and` and `or` is used instead of `if` and `else`. That got me wondering, which one of them is efficient in terms of time complexity. And is there a way to use `and` and  `or` in complex if-else branching, Even more on what's happening behind the scene

Comment: @xdhmoore the `and` and `or` operators work for *any* object that supports being evaluated in a boolean context, so there are *many* more possible combinations to test.

Comment: @mkrieger1 yeah I think you're right. Especially since the AND/OR operators don't convert to Boolean but pass thru the original value as trincot's answer mentions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original expression makes use of the fact that a boolean operator like `and` and `or` always evaluates to one of the operands, not necessarily a boolean. This is somewhat an extension to the mathematical notion of boolean logic where all involved values are booleans.

So:

- if the left operand of an `and` operator is:

  - *truthy*, the operation will evaluate to whatever the *second* operand is.
  - *falsy*, the operation will evaluate to whatever the *first* (falsy) operand is.
- if the left operand of an `or` operator is:

  - *truthy*, the operation will evaluate to whatever the *first* (truthy) operand is.
  - *falsy*, the operation will evaluate to whatever the *second* operand is.

If you apply those rules to the expression, you can see that the first expression is a true boolean. In case it is false, the `and` operation will also evaluate to false, which then serves as the left operand to the `or` operator. By consequence, the `or` operation will evaluate to the rightmost operand, i.e. to `'.'`.

If on the other hand the first expression is True, then the `and` operator will evaluate to the second operand, i.e. `chr(i)`. That value happens to be *always* truthy, as it can never be the empty string, and so the `or` operation will just evaluate to that and will not even consider the final operand.

So the two constructs are equivalent, but only when the middle operand (in this case `chr(i)`) is always truthy.

Comment: Ok, this wonderful explanation clears it, But doesn't this go against Zen Of Python - Readability counts.

Comment: Sure, for readability I would also go with `if...else`, but I'm sure there is a group of coders who feel otherwise. In the end it is a matter of opinion.